# How to: check for nil on every value before presentation of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Below I have a tableView delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    lessonView?.lessonName = (capturedLessons?[indexPath.row].name)!

    lessonView?.instructorGradedTracked = capturedLessons![indexPath.row].instructorGraded!

    lessonView?.expectedCompletionTimeTracked = capturedLessons![indexPath.row].expectedCompletionTime!

    self.present(self.lessonView!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

lessonName: String
instructorGraded: Bool
expectedCompletionTime: Int
```

I am having trouble setting up a check for nil on the bool and int values. What is the best practice approach to implementing this error handling?

Comment: For this code to pass `lessonView` should not be nil so no meaning of making it optional

Comment: Agreed. You seem very confident than `lessonView` and `capturedLessons` cannot be nil, so why are they Optional in the first place? Could you make them non-optional? In particular, `capturedLessons` is an array, so how is nil different than `[]`? Making that non-optional would get rid of most of your headaches here. Similarly, why would you have an optional bool and int? What does it mean for them to be nil? If nil has no special meaning, then do not use an Optional. If it does have a special meaning, then you need logic to apply that meaning. Most variables should not be Optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
guard let item = capturedLessons?[indexPath.row] ,let name = item.name,  let graded = item.instructorGraded , let completionTime = item.expectedCompletionTime else { return }
lessonView?.lessonName = name
lessonView?.instructorGradedTracked = graded
lessonView?.expectedCompletionTimeTracked = completionTime
self.present(self.lessonView!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these safe unwraps:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

guard let lessonView = lessonView,
    let lesson = capturedLesson?[indexPath.row], 
    let name = lesson.name, 
    let graded = lesson.instructorGraded, 
    let completionTime = lesson.expectedCompletionTime
else { 
    // could not unwrap: something is nil
    return 
}

lessonView.lessonName = name
lessonView.instructorGradedTracked = graded
lessonView.expectedCompletionTimeTracked = completionTime
self.present(lessonView, animated: true)
```

The benefit of this is that you have no `!`s hanging around, which could be `nil` and crash your app when force unwrapped.